# Do I need a transit visa in Melbourne en route to Wellington?

Tags: transit-visas, australia, iranian-citizens

I want to buy a ticket from Dubai to Wellington NZ. The flight is Dubai - Melbourne - Wellington. It is all one ticket, and I will not need my luggage in any location except the final destination. Do I need a transit visa for Australia? I am an Iran citizen with a valid NZ student visa.

Answer (score 3):

Given your nationality I believe you will need a [Transit Visa (subclass 771)](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771#Overview) in order to transit Melbourne.

Note that link says for this visa:

> Stay: No longer than 72 hours
>
> Cost: Free
>
> Processing times:
>
> 25% of
> applications: 1 day
>
> 50% of applications: 5 days
>
> 75% of applications:
> 13 days
>
> 90% of applications: 20 days

Unless there is something we don't know about, it seems that you would not be eligible for a visa free transit, as seen in [this link](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa).

Comment: Thanks. Yep I need and its free